# How do we tell if ばかり means "about" or "only"?

Tags: grammar, particle-ばかり

If [ばかり](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/%7Ejwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUE%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A) could mean **approximately; about;** and could also mean **only; merely; nothing but;**, then how should we know if this sentence **５０００円ばかりもっている。** means:

> 1. I have about 5000 yen.

or

> 2. I have only 5000 yen.

Comment: I've never heard of it meaning "about".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. ばかり after **an amount or a quantity** means 'approximately', 'about':

   > ５０００円ばかりもっている。→ I have **about** 5,000 yen.
   >
   > 僕はここ３年ばかりあの人に会わない。→ I haven't seen him for about three years.
2. The sense of 'only', 'just' works **after a verb**:

   > 列車はたった今ついたばかりです。→ The train has just arrived here.

   or a **noun/pronoun** (not indicating a quantity):

   > あの人は勉強 ばかりしていて... → All he does is study

Note that ばかりに, ばかりか etc. also exist and work differently.

As @Scott just pointed out, in your example, you would use だけ or しか (+negative) to mean "only".

Answer (score 4):

If the verb is past tense it means "just" happened.
If the verb is -te iru it means only.

There are about 3 or 4 other uses that arent used as much. bakarini nado...

> ×　５０００円ばかりもっている。 doesnt sound right.
>
> ○　５０００円だけ持ってる
>
> ○　５０００円しか持ってない

Comment: `５０００円ばかりもっている。` sounds perfectly right. It means "I have as much as 5000 yen."