# usage of ばかり in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I only know the grammar usage of ばかり as full of___ but I don't know how to parse this sentence.

> 少しばかり　しゃくですが

Comment: 少しばかり means "just a bit of...." ばかりoften means "just"

Comment: related/duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3735/correct-usage-of-%e3%81%b0%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a

Answer (score 1):

～ばかり has many functions, one of which is "about ～", "to the extent of ～". It can form an adverbial expression.

- 少しばかり(の): [no-adj, adv] a little
- わずかばかり(の): [no-adj, adv] slight / slightly
- ちょっとばかり(の): [no-adj, adv] a bit (of)
- 3日ばかり待った。
  I waited for **about** three days.
- 10万円ばかり払えばいいパソコンが買える。
  You can buy a good computer if you pay 100,000 yen **or so**.

Practically you can remember 少しばかり / わずかばかり / ちょっとばかり as set phrases that works as an adverb.